# How to compile into a binary for each optimization level with gcc and make?

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, gnu-make

I have a sourcefile `benchmark.c` and I want to build it with each compiler optimization level.
Is there a way to achieve this automatically instead of providing every single flag manually like this?

```
all:
    gcc benchmark.c -o benchmark-O0 -O0
    gcc benchmark.c -o benchmark-O1 -O1
    gcc benchmark.c -o benchmark-O2 -O2
    gcc benchmark.c -o benchmark-O3 -O3
```

I'd like to have a more general method.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What part of it do you want to automate?  More importantly, you've got something that looks like it works, and is pretty clear and simple, so what's actually wrong  with it?

Answer (score 1):

You're thinking of a for loop?

```
all:
    for level in O0 O1 O2 O3; do \
        gcc benchmark.c -$level benchmark-$level \
    done
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through a list of words, each containing the digit that sets the optimization option, and each time call a canned recipe which invokes the appropriate command:

```
LIST := 0 1 2 3

define RUN

gcc benchmark.c -o benchmark-O$1 -O$1

endef   

all:  
    $(foreach variable,$(LIST),$(call RUN,$(variable)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're assuming GNU make, you might as well use GNU features such as functions.  Here's one way you could do the job in what seems to me to be in a reasonably make-like idiom:

```
baseexe := benchmark
levels  := 0 1 2 3 s
files   := $(foreach level,$(levels),$(baseexe)-O$(level))

all: $(files)

$(files): $(baseexe).c
    gcc $(subst $(baseexe),,$@) $< -o $@
```

There are two or three bits of magic there:

- the definition of the `files` make variable uses GNU's `foreach` make function to build the list of target files from the base name and list of optimization levels.
- (following you) the names of the target files encode the optimization option, so
- the build recipe can and does use GNU's `subst` make function to extract the optimization option from each target name.

You'll have to judge whether that somewhat arcane 8-line (including two blank) makefile is better for your purposes than what you started with.  As for me, I'd take your plain and simple starting version.